# Firebase Functions app_remove , get userid

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I am trying to create a new entry (with userid) in my firebase database as soon as a user removes my app. (Qndroid)

```
'use strict';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.appremoved = functions.analytics.event('app_remove').onLog(event => {
  console.log("App remove detected");

  var user = admin.auth().currentUser;
  var uid;

  const uid2 = event.data.user.userId;
  console.log("App remove detected2:" + uid2);

  if (user != null) {
    uid = user.uid;
    console.log("User object not empty" );
    admin.database().ref('/user_events/'+uid + "/"+Date.now()).set("app_remove");
  }
});
```

I created two variables to get the user id, but both of them are undefined.

uid2 is undefined, and user is null.

I also tried

```
const user = event.data.user;
```

But it is also null

How do I get the userid of the user that removed the app?

Comment: How you got appInstanceId in application if you do it ? I try to get it but unsuccess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637005/get-appinstanceid-in-android-app?noredirect=1#comment90239286_51637221

Comment: Hi Sharpless, I used this code but this event(functions.analytics.event('app_remove'))  is not executing do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Calling `admin.auth().currentUser` gets you the administrative user that is running the admin SDK. This user does not have a UID. And even if they did, it wouldn't be the user that removed the app.

Calling `event.data.user.userId` gives you the user ID that your app may have set via the [`setUserId` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setUserId). If you didn't set a UserId, the call won't give you any value.

Comment: is there any other way to get an ID, so I can track when a user removes the app? I will do the same when he installs it, so I can see how long it takes for users to remove the app. But I need some way to know which user is who

Comment: Ok, I am currently using the "user.appInfo.appInstanceId" to identify the user. Which is good enough for now