# How to get user email using firebase analytics event parameter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm making app using firebase on back-end part. User can log in  myApp using google account and can backup their data.

I want to delete some doc at cloud when user uninstall myApp.
`collection` ID is user email.
So I need to know user email but I don't know how to get this.

```
exports.appUninstall = functions.analytics.event("app_remove").onLog((event)=>{
  const userEmail = event.user.email;
  database.doc(userEmail + "/user_logged_in").delete();
  return console.log("Deleted user_logged_in because user uninstalled app");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the structure you currently have. As you can see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_analytics_.analyticseventbuilder#onlog), the `onLog()` returns a [`AnalyticsEvent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_analytics_.analyticsevent#user) object that has a [`UserDimensions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_analytics_.userdimensions) object inside of it, however, that object stores the `userId` and an object with the `userProperties`.

I can' t say for sure that this `userProperties` will store the email of your user so you can fetch in firestore, so you need to test this. If not, you will have to find a way get the user document with it's `userId`, maybe by adding it to the document itself on creation.

This would be easier if you changed the documentId to be the `userId` instead of the `email`, if you do that you can simply use the mentioned `userId` of the event to get the document and delete it.

Comment: Wow, just now I've solve this problem using `userId`. lol. I missed the method `setUserId()`, but I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45146563/14434806)